# How can I declare the output of a python function with a custom data structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to declare the type of the output for a function and it is a list of dictionaries. How can I declare it in the function definition?

```py
x = [['book', 55], ['magazine', 30]]


def my_function(x: list) -> list:
    return [{f'{i[0]}': f'{i[1]}'} for i in iter(x)]


print(my_function(x))
```

```
[{'book': 55}, {'magazine': 30}]
```

Comment: Those are not dictionaries, those are [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)s that contain a single `str`.  You probably meant to do `{f'{i[0]}': f'{i[1]}'}`

Comment: yes! you're right, my bad, fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify what type is contained in a container, you can use the subscript operator.  For example:

```
def my_function(x: list[typing.Any]) -> list[dict[str, str]]:
    ...
```

Note that this syntax is only valid starting with Python 3.9.  If you are on an older version, you have to instead use the type aliases defined in the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) package:

```
def my_function(x: typing.List[typing.Any]) -> typing.List[typing.Dict[str, str]]:
    ...
```

Comment: To use them before 3.9 you can also import `from __future__ import annotations` so the first example is a good solution all in all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the typing module for this (and possibly `list` and `dict` directly in the most recent versions of Python):

```
from typing import List, Dict

def my_function(x: list) -> List[Dict[str,str]]:
```